# Make select based loop as responsive as possible

Tags: c++, multithreading, select

This thread will be very responsive to network activity but can be guaranteed to process the message queue only as often as 100 times a second. I can keep reducing the timeout but after a certain point I will be busy-waiting and chewing up CPU. Is it true that this solution is about as good as I'll get without switching to another method?

```
// semi pseudocode
while (1) {
  process_thread_message_queue(); // function returns near-instantly
  struct timeval t;
  t.tv_sec = 0;
  t.tv_usec = 10 * 1000; // 10ms = 0.01s
  if (select(n,&fdset,0,0,t)) // see if there are incoming packets for next 1/100 sec
  {
    ... // respond with more packets or processing
  }
}
```

Comment: Your assertion is correct, using this technique you're bound to minimum latency. You cannot likely however busy-loop with the normal `select` function. You'll be found to minimum time overhead from the OS kernel. Of course, it all greatly depends on the OS and how `select` is implemented.

Comment: According to this code, if when you talk of "process the message queue", you mean calling `process_thread_message_queue`, then potentially you will call it more than 100 times a second - infact, the number of times you call it depends on what you are passing into `select` and the traffic. The time you pass to `select` (as you probably realise) is a timeout, so 100 is the *minimum* number of times `process_thread_message_queue` will get called...

Comment: @Nim You are absolutely correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what your OS provides for your. On Windows you can wait for a thread message and a bunch of handles **simultaneously** using MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx. This solves your problem. On other OS you should have something similar.